# How do I get two colors from one color

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to use this method to display two different colors borders of a specific color

[image]

Is there any way to implement with php or jQuery ...

sorry for my english is too bad

thanks Rory McCrossan

Comment: These are not two different colors. Its list which shows menu. And border of list element is causing two color effect.

Comment: Huh what? Which different colors?

Comment: Colors can be random

Comment: Easier solution, use white and black at 50% alpha for the top/bottom borders.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easier method (assuming the browsers you're aiming to support work with it) would be to use `rgba` values for the top/bottom border of the `li`. This way the browser will calculate the colour required itself. Try this:

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: "arial", "sans-serif";
}
ul.first { background-color: #3B5998; }
ul.second { background-color: #C00; }
li {
    padding: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<ul class="first">
    <li>Blackberry</li>
    <li>Demo Blog With Map</li>
    <li>Archive Page Full</li>
    <li>404 Error</li>
    <li>Android</li>
</ul>
<ul class="second">
    <li>Blackberry</li>
    <li>Demo Blog With Map</li>
    <li>Archive Page Full</li>
    <li>404 Error</li>
    <li>Android</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: nice job it's perfect

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the color-value of a image you can use the following statement:

```
int $val = imagecolorat ( resource $image , int $pos_x , int $pos_y )
```

Comment: no from specific color it's not image it's background color

Answer (score 0):

Try This. Hope it helps

```css
ul.horizontal {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
ul.horizontal li {
   border: 1px solid #ccc;    
}
ul.horizontal {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 3em 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
ul.horizontal li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #069;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}
ul.horizontal li a:hover {
    color: #c00;
    background-color: #fff;
}
ul.horizontal li a.active {
    background-color: rgb(201, 205, 248);
}
```

```html
<ul class="horizontal" id="nav">
 <li><a href="#" class="active">About Us</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Our Products</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">FAQs</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hGF54/14/)